# Creating a delayed search with a delay reset

Tags: javascript

I have a search function that I need to fire about 2 seconds after the user stops typing in a search bar (which then filters entries of a table). If the user types or otherwise edits the contents of the search bar within those 2 seconds, the timer resets back to 2 seconds before the search request fires.
If I need to, I will post example code of what I have if requested, but I have little idea what should be included at the moment.

Edit: Tags and fact that the project is in Laravel is irrelevant.

Comment: You've basically described the exact solution in words, so where are you stuck?  Do you just need to see this articulated in JavaScript?  Normally, since this is a coding site, yes, we would prefer to see the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a laravel problem but off `JavaScript`

this should get you started in what you're trying to achieve:

```
var countDown;
const functionForSearching=()=>{
 //do your searching here
}

const delayedSearch() {
  clearTimeout(countDown); 
  countDown = setTimeout(()=>{
    //call your search Function Here
    functionForSeaching()
  },2000); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this out and see from that point onwards. Will also update the tags to be more accurate.

Comment: ok that's better. if it helps you, when done you can mark it as answered